# Sent Bytes is not equal to Received Bytes in C++ Socket Prg

Tags: c++, image, sockets, binary, recv

I have client and server to transport images. Client sends image binary and server receives them and stores. I used buff vector to store binary.

Client Side:

```
bytes_sent = send(socketfd, &fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), 0);
bytes_sent = send(socketfd, &fileContents[0], fileSize, 0);
```

Server Side:

```
bytes_received = recv(new_sd, &temp.imageSize, sizeof(temp.imageSize), 0);
bytes_received = recv(new_sd, &buff[0], buff.size(), 0);

            if(bytes_received < 0)
                break; //Error

            if(bytes_received == 0)
                break; //Disconnect

            img.write(&buff[8], temp.imageSize);
```

Printed bytes_received and bytes_sent, **result:** `bytes_received = 8 + bytes_sent`. I opened created image with vim(or notepad) , there was `/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00` extra characters at the beginning of image. To solve this problem i have changed buff[0] to buff[8], now received image works well.

How can i receive binary files without these 8 /00 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to transport binary file is:

- when the sender sends the file, close the connection socket when the reading from file is complete
- sending is complete In receiver side, receive until the connection is
  closed by the sender.

example:

```
 sender:

file = open_file("file_name",read_binary)
while(file.read(bytes)!=null){
 send(toreceiver_socket,read_data);
}
file.close()
toreceiver_socket.close()


 receiver

file = open_file("file_name",write_binary)
while(sender_socket_not_closed){
 data = sendersocket.receive()
 file.write()
}
file.close()
```

I have just show how this can be achieved. This will ensure that file is transffered successfully.